# Boost ASIO IPv6 join_group does not work on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I am attempting to open an IPv6 multicast listen port on OSX but am getting an error code 49 when attempting to run the "join_group" option.  Here is a sample of the code causing the probem:

```
ip6_listen=boost::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket>(io_service);
ip6_listen->open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v6());
ip6_listen->set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
ip6_listen->bind(boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v6::any(),ANNOUNCE_PORT));
ip6_listen->set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(boost::asio::ip::address_v6::from_string("FF01::AC22"))); //Throws error "49"
```

It is not clear why this is throwing an error because it works properly on Windows and Linux. Why is this error occurring only on OSX?

Comment: Error 49 is 'Can't assign requested address'; have you tried other address (or other simple network connection code) on the OSX system to ensure it's not some other possible issue or that you don't have something else bound to that socket address/port?

Comment: The binding works fine. It is the last line "join_group" that does not work.  Yes, I have tried other multicast addresses.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, the OS can't determine the interface used to join the group automatically.
You can set the interface index manually ([documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__multicast__outbound_interface.html)):

```cpp
ip6_listen->set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::outbound_interface(0);
```

As for how to get the interface index, you can use this code:

```cpp
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

std::vector<uint32_t> get_v6_ifindices {
    std::vector<uint32_t> res;
    ifaddrs *ifs;
    if (getifaddrs(&ifs)) {
        std::cerr << "Error enumerating interfaces: " << errno << '\n';
        return res;
    }
    for (auto addr = ifs; addr != nullptr; addr = addr->ifa_next) {
        // No address? Skip.
        if (addr->ifa_addr == nullptr) continue;
        // Interface doesn't support multicast? Skip.
        if (!(addr->ifa_flags & IFF_MULTICAST)) continue;
        // Interface isn't active? Skip.
        if (!(addr->ifa_flags & IFF_UP)) continue;

        uint32_t idx = if_nametoindex(addr->ifa_name);
        ifaces[idx].name = addr->

        switch (addr->ifa_addr->sa_family) {
        case AF_INET: auto v4addr = ntohl(((sockaddr_in *)addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr); break;
        case AF_INET6: {
            res.push_back(idx);
            auto sa_in6 = (sockaddr_in6 *)addr->ifa_addr;
            auto v6addr = (const unsigned char *)&sa_in6->sin6_addr;
        }
#ifdef __APPLE__
        case AF_CCITT: break;
        case AF_LINK: break;
#else
        case AF_PACKET: break;
#endif
        default: std::clog << "Unknown interface type " << static_cast<int>(addr->ifa_addr->sa_family) << '\n';
        }
    }
    freeifaddrs(ifs);
    return res;
}
```